# What does undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 mean?

Tags: eigen, glew

I am trying to build eigen on my Mac Air with Lion. I downloaded eigen3 (from http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) and have successfully run `make install`. However, when I try to run `make check`, I get the following error.

```
[  1%] Built target sparse_extra_2
Linking CXX executable openglsupport
ld: warning: ignoring file /System/Library/Frameworks//GLEW.framework/GLEW,
            missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glewExperimental", referenced from:
      test_openglsupport() in openglsupport.cpp.o
  "_glewInit", referenced from:
      test_openglsupport() in openglsupport.cpp.o
  "_glBegin", referenced from:
      test_openglsupport() in openglsupport.cpp.o
```

I feel that this issue has to do with glew. I am now trying to install different versions of glew, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Any advice on how to resolve the error? What does undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 mean anyway?

Comment: Ok ... for now, I'm bypassing this error by going into the C++ and returning in the `test_openglsupport` function before any of the OpenGL-related calls in `openglsupport.cpp` are made. Very sketchy way of bypassing the error, but oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably means your installation of GLEW is incomplete. You can properly disable testing of OpenGL with `cmake . -DEIGEN_TEST_NO_OPENGL=ON`. Finally, note that Eigen is a header only library, so there is nothing to compile to use it.